# Add Migration: Unable to create an object of type AppContext

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have a .NET 5 solution that contains two projects (DataLayer and ServiceLayer).
In DataLayer i have the following DbContext:

```
internal class ApplicationContext
    : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly);
    }
}
```

and the following DbContextFactory:

```
internal sealed class ContextFactory
    : IDbContextFactory<ApplicationContext>
{
    public ContextFactory(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options)
    {
        Options = options ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
    }

    private DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> Options { get; }

    public ApplicationContext CreateDbContext()
    {
        return new ApplicationContext(Options);
    }
}
```

which i use in each repository ctor:

```
 public UserRepository(IDbContextFactory<ApplicationContext> contextFactory) { ... }
```

And the services initialization for DbContextFactory:

```
services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationContext>(options =>
{
    options
    .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString);
});
```

The problem is when i try to create a migration i get the following message:

> Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 for both of commands:

**Add-Migration Initial**

**dotnet ef migrations add Initial --project DataLayer**

I also have to mention that both projects are plain .NET 5 library projects and, in the service layer project, i build the ServiceCollection manually: `var services = new ServiceCollection();`

I searched for solutions but i didn't find any.

Thanks

Comment: If it is asp.net core, why are you even using ContextFactory ? i mean context can easily be initialized by the DI in runtime with startup.

Comment: @AVTUNEY it's needed for ef migration tool `dotnet ef migrations ...`

Comment: @mtkachenko i know that and understand, but this person said he is using Add-Migration. it automatically means that he is using Visual Studio On windows. i dont think there is any need of ef core tool packages. if it were VsMac, or even Visual Studio Code then it would be correct to use.

Comment: @AVTUNEY `dotnet ef migrations add ..` is a cross platform.

Comment: @mtkachenko i know, talking about him.

Comment: @AVTUNEY The author wants to add a new migration. It means he uses `dotnet ef tools` as described in official documentation. I didn't catch what do you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can't inject anything into constructor. You should use the way described in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory):

```
public class BloggingContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<BloggingContext>
{
    public BloggingContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=blog.db");

        return new BloggingContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Then you can pass any parameters through `args`:

```
dotnet ef database update -- --environment Production --connectionstring "some_connection_string"
```

Comment: Changing to IDesignTimeDbContextFactory solved the problem but, i wonder how and when args are used (from CreateDbContext(string[] args) method).

Comment: Just read the official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli (it's actually a link from your error): `The -- token directs dotnet ef to treat everything that follows as an argument and not try to parse them as options. Any extra arguments not used by dotnet ef are forwarded to the app.` Also check arguments from an example in my answer